# I can't get TryCatch register errors omdbapi in R

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch, imdb

I'm trying to extend a movie database by using the omdbapi package in R. But in my loop for matching genres with titles, it sometimes gives the error:

> "Movie not found! get_countries() expects an omdb object".

Which isn't a problem, but it's stops my for-loop. So I tried 'tryCatch, but somehow isn't able to register the error. Maybe because the error structure is different? Any ideas how to solve it?

PS: temporary is just a test variable

code:

```
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/omdbapi")   
library(omdbapi)
library(dplyr)

temporary = tryCatch(
   get_countries(find_by_title(as.character("faketitle"))) , 
   error=function(e) loadError <<- FALSE)

temporary
```

Lastly, here is an example of output. I don't understand why the temp2 gives back FALSE as temp3 does.

```
> temp1 = tryCatch(
    get_countries(find_by_title(as.character("spectre"))) , 
    error=function(e) loadError <<- FALSE)
> temp1
[1] "UK"  "USA"
> temp2 = tryCatch(
    get_countries(find_by_title(as.character("faketitle"))) , 
    error=function(e) loadError <<- FALSE)
Movie not found!
get_countries() expects an omdb object
> temp2
NULL
> temp3 = tryCatch(
    get_countries(find_by_title(as.character(faketitle))) ,
    error=function(e) loadError <<- FALSE)
> temp3
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: What's the problem, exactly? You say "isn't able to register", but it isn't clear what you mean by that. (BTW: realize that `loadError <<- FALSE` will also return `FALSE` to `temporary` (same reason `x <- y <- 1` works).)

Comment: `temp3` is returning `FALSE` because (I'm guessing) you have not defined a variable named `faketitle`, so there is an error of `Error: object 'faketitle' not found` being caught by `tryCatch`. My guess is that the function is not using `stop` to produce an error, it is merely sending a message to the console and returning `NULL`. (`tryCatch` will catch `stop`s, not `return(NULL)`.)

Comment: Perhaps you should capture the output from `find_by_title`, assess its validity (empty data.frame means nothing found), and only if valid call `get_countries`.

Comment: Aha, I get it. Included 'if (is.null(temp)==TRUE) next' in the loop and now it works. Super thanks!